# Installing Ubuntu Touch Failed Nexus 7 2012

Tags: ubuntu-touch, adb

I tried to install the trusty version of Ubuntu Touch on my 2012 Nexus 7. I followed the directions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) and I entered

```
sudo ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap
```

until my terminal returned

```
Cannot push /home/nick/.cache/ubuntuimages/devel/grouper/version-194.tar.xz to device
```

(I also tried to do it manually, with that failing as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that support for the **Nexus 7** (gen 1) has been dropped, and this method won't work any more. This was announced on **03-Mar-2014** (as noted below).

---

**In formal terms:**

*Support (as reference hardware) for the **Nexus 7** (original model) is now deprecated, with development now focused on: **Nexus 4** smartphone, **Nexus 7 (2013)** tablet, and **Nexus 10** tablet.*

### See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

> **Supported devices and codenames**
>
> The table below lists the supported devices and their corresponding factory images, ..

---

See also:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/ubuntu-touch-wont-support-nexus-5-will-drop-support-nexus-7-10

> **Nexus Device Support Dropped**
>
> Along with no dice for the Nexus 5, moving Ubuntu Touch to an Android 4.4 enablement stack has resulted in further decisions on which devices should remain “officially supported”.
>
> From the end of January official builds for three of the four currently supported Nexus devices will be discontinued, affecting users of:
>
> - Nexus 10 (2012)
> - Nexus 7 (2012)
> - Galaxy Nexus
>
> ..

### **PLEASE NOTE:**

*This article does not exactly match current support, as **Nexus 10** in still (for the moment) being supported. However, focus (going forward) is definitely on the **Nexus 4** (for phone), and **Nexus 7 (2013)** (for tablet).*

Answer (score -1):

The original 2012 model's support has been made deprecate in favour of the newer (per-se) 2013 model.